# Performance is low when the engine type is InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, wapt

If anyone can help on this?

I am using `MySQL 5.1.47` and recently I have changed the engine type of 4 main tables of my application to `InnoDB` , previously it was `MyISAM`.

I am doing Load testing using WAPT Pro Trial Version , when I am connected to the database where my four main tables are of `InnoDB` average response time for 5 users is 3.1 sec whereas when connected to `MyISAM`, it is only `0.58 sec`.

How can I improve the performance ? The below parameters have been added in my.cnf file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G &
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=2
```

Do I really have to upgrade the version of `MySQL` in my machine to the latest one or do I have to set some other parameters other than the two parameters which I have mentioned above.

My application has 70 % selects and 30 % inserts all the time

Comment: Check this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Answer (score 0):

If possible, set innodb_buffer_pool_size as large as the total size of your tables.